GSC shows that there many URLs are " Crawled - currently not indexed". I checked and almost all of them are indexed. Why?
I've noticed that in Google Search Console (GSC), there are numerous pages listed under "Crawled - currently not indexed," even though most of them are actually indexed. When I clicked "validate" it still shows "Failed." Why could this be happening, and is there a way to fix it?

When you say "actually indexed", I assume you mean you've seen them in the SERPs and for the exact same URL as listed in Google?

I checked them in "Inspect" on GSC, and they are shown as indexed. That's why I say they are actually indexed. I don't know how Google can say they are indexed and at the same time show them under "crawled - currently not indexed"

There is a lag between actual indexing, the URL inspection status and then what is reported in the lists.

So, these are of course just guesses.
But check if your pages appear in the search results using the operator site:yourdomain.com. If everything seems fine, then it’s likely either a delay, as mentioned in the comment above, or an issue on GSC's side, which will probably get fixed.
Alternatively, you can try resubmitting the pages for indexing after some time.
